# LiveData vs Parcelable

Tags: android, firestore, livedata

Прошу подсказать какое решение работает быстрее?

Есть класс User с полями имя, адрес и т.д. Поля класса наполняются данными из FireStore.

Раньше передавал данные через Intent c Parcelable. 
Сейчас переделал класс в LiveData. Так как класс постоянно растет озадачился вопросом быстродействия. Прошу подсказать, если кто сталкивался.